# Android API for inter-device communication

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is an API that allows for direct communication between two or more Android devices, particularly for real-time multiplayer gaming. For example, is Bluetooth communication between two devices for the purpose of gaming?

EDIT: I do not have a (reliable) server so I cannot consider it as an option. I am looking for an API that strictly uses direct device communication (so no servers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://androidforums.com/android-games/57-mages-multiplayer-android-game-engine-chess-game-included.html

Here is one multiplayer engine i have run across when exploring networking options. I have not used it though so I cannot give any insightful opinion about it.

Generally I tend to lean towards creating my own tcp client / server solution. Of course the best choice for you depends on what type game / application you are looking to make. Generally if you plan to have a good number of users on at a single given time (more than 3+) P2P is strayed away from. That being said i have also yet to see a well working solution for a client / server application over bluetooth, which leaves you with traditional networking strategies.

Comment: Also forgot to mention wifi direct. Wifi direct allows you to communicate directly via wifi without the need for a wifi hotspot to communicate between devices. Wifi direct is much more flexible than bluetooth, however it only exists at this point on the nexus galaxy and smartphones running android 4.0 from what i know.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will most likely be interested in making a game with up to two players. I do not have a server (or a reliable one) for a serious network game, so I opted for direct communication between devices.

Comment: yeah that is generally an issue, however via wifi doesnt mean you always need a server. You can have a client act as a client/server and just have that user designated as the client/server receive and send the data calls, but this is only a valid choice again for not a huge number of players... no mmo's @dan does the engine I referred you to have anything that could help?

Comment: If it allows one device to act as a server, then I will definitely look into it. Thanks a lot for the find!

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are APIs for that now.

"Nearby Connections is a peer-to-peer networking API that allows apps to easily discover, connect to, and exchange data with nearby devices in real-time, regardless of network connectivity."
https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview

Also see:

Wifi P2P
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p

Overview on what to select:
https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly

PS I know this is an old question but it still ranks very high on search engines, therefore I add this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing Peer-2-Peer, then Bluetooth and/or NFC would be your best bets. I would suggest to using the "Internet" approach through Wifi as it offers more flexibility.

Comment: I would not recomend nfc as its active range is .2 meters and transfers very small amounts of data, most common applications are very close range eg. Bump.