# Transmit extra digit to called party when making a call?

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

I'd like to trasmit data (in the form of a single extra digit) to the called party when making a call. Both users naturally need to have my app installed.

*For example:*  `Person A` makes a call to `Person B`, my app cancels the outgoing call, appends a "`*1`" (e.g.) to the called number and re-initiates the call. My app on `Person B`'s phone listens to incoming calls and extracts the extra digit from the called number.

Is something like this possible? Please note that I can't use `public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {}` for this, since `incomingNumber`is the *caller's* (`Person A`'s) number, not the *called* number. I need to be able to extract the extra-digit *before the call has been picked up*, so I can't use `p`or `w`DTMF-dial-codes.

I've got the "intercept-and-redial"-portion on the caller's side, and the "listen for incoming calls"-portion of the app working, I just can't figure out how to A) transmit the digit so that it arrives at the called party's phone (rather than being dropped by the carrier) and B)  get the *called* number on the receiver's phone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think, but I'm not sure, that you can't just transmit data like this. The reason is that the carrier directs calls with those numbers (codes). Transmitting an extra number(or an extra single digit) means wrong (or incorrect) number and will probably cancel the call. What you want to do seems to me like a way to manipulate the network, but I don't think it's possible. The data center of the carrier has probably at least some kind of a check on this.

I don't know why you need those symbols "*1" to be transmitted, but since this is hardcoded, it can easily be hardcoded into your application too. I think that you can use the telephone number to identify the calling party, but if you need to transfer information dynamically this way, it should not be possible.

Maybe you should try communicating directly with the other device, which has your app installed. Here's an interesting [THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853305/android-api-for-inter-device-communication) about this, even though there, this kind of communication is used for multiplayer games it provides a way for the devices to communicate.

Comment: Hi g00dy, thanks for your reply! I've already tried to use a web-script to communicate the digit to the called party, but this takes too long (the call itself is "quicker" than the device-server-device communication). I think the carriers don't care about extra digits (if you're calling a landline, you can add codes like "w234" to call an extension using the corporate switchboard), and adding a few zeros (e.g.) to a number doesn't affect the call (but they might be filtered by the carrier, I don't know).